# Finding the correct difference with dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary that changes items in a time order, I preserve the previous state in a global var for comparison.  I'm trying to determine if there is a difference between them and what that difference is.  Also, was the difference an add, subtract, or modification to the 2nd dict from the first.

A symmetric difference using set tells me what changed, but not whether it was an add or subtract.  So that doesn't work.

For reference, the dictionaries comparison may look like:

```
a = {419: 'test'}
b = {419: 'test', 418: 'new'}
```

In which case, I'd want to spit out `{418: 'new'}` was added.

Another case may be:

```
a = {419: 'test'}
b = {419: 'test1234'}
```

I would want to spit out `{419: 'test1234'}` was modified.

Comment: Why is this tagged Python 3 if you are using Python 2 syntax?

Comment: I can use either Python 2 or 3, but I would prefer 3.  The syntax provided is how the API displays the data.

Comment: Yeah, you should provide [mcve]. Currently what you are posting is a `SyntaxError` in Python 3, but it happens to be ok Python 2, were an `L` was used to denote a `long` literal

Comment: This seems *maybe*  more of a tagging issue than an MCV issue.  The `L` is not really the point of the question (I can simply remove it).  For the sake of ending the discussion, i'll remove the `L` from the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use symmetric difference, use the differences one at a time:

```
>>> a = {419: 'test'}
>>> b = {419: 'test', 418: 'new'}
>>> removed = a.items() - b.items()
>>> removed
set()
>>> if removed: print("removed: ", *removed)
...
>>> added = b.items() - a.items()
>>>
>>> added
{(418, 'new')}
>>> if added: print("added: ", *added)
...
added:  (418, 'new')
```

Now, to handle the "changed" by checking if the item was in the original dict (just the key) after the difference.

Comment: I considered this approach.  I just thought there might be a faster method.

Comment: @Shawn what do you mean by "faster"? *Runtime*?

Comment: The python script would need to perform each of the `-` operations per iteration. It's a pretty big script already and I'm trying to squeeze as much performance as possible.  In any case, this should do the job.